# In function `_start': (.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main' collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Tags: c++, g++

I'm new to g++ and compiling my C++ code in LINUX.
I'm trying to connect several .o files as .lib using g++.

This is the command that I used "g++ -o ../fuzzy/fuzzy.lib example1.o example2.o" and got this error. Even though I try to connect a single object file and make a .lib, it doesn't work.

Your help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make a static library, use `ar`:

```
ar rcs mylibrary.a a.o b.o c.o
```

To make a shared library, use `gcc` to link:

```
gcc -o mylibrary.so -shared a.o b.o. c.o
```

Comment: @ Kerrek SB: great!! Is this how I would  link the static library to .cpp file?            g++ -o nervolver -Wno-deprecated mylibrary.a example.cpp

Comment: @parthpatel: Just add it to your list of files, but at the end: `g++ -o nervolver example.cpp mylibrary.a`

Answer (score 5):

If you are trying to build a library, the options depend on whether you want to build a static or a shared library. For example,

```
# shared library
g++ -shared -o name.so obj1.o obj2.o obj3.o
```

A static library is essentially an archive, which you can build from the `.o` files using the `ar` command.

```
ar <options> mylib.a obj1.o obj2.o obj3.o
```

If you are trying to compile an object file, you need to pass the `-c` option:

```
g++ -c ....
```

Otherwise, `g++` attempts to compile an executable, and this requires a [`main` function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_function).

Comment: i'm using g++ -c when i'm compiling .cpp file.                      so should my command look like this? "g++ -c name1.lib example1.o example2.o"

Comment: @parthpatel my answer tells you how to build a static library.

Comment: I'm not sure, but doesn't `-fpic` also have to be passed to each compilation step?

Comment: @KerrekSB Good catch. Actually I think it only has to be passed to the compilation steps, not the library building one. I removed it. I may add a note about it later.